# c# run batch file on top of Top Most window

Tags: c#, batch-file, topmost

I know this question was asked several times, but still I couldn't make it work.

I have a top most - full screen window which on a button click needs to run a batch file with numerous commands, some of them open user interaction window.

As a starter, just to check that I'm on the right way, I'm trying to run a batch file with the command `call notepad`.
My goal is that the notepad will be on top of my caller window.

This is mainly trial and error now, so excuse me for the weird code.

**Declarations and consts:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
```

**Execution:**

```
static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process = Process.Start("c:\\TestFolder\\runNotepad.bat");

    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
}
```

**runNotepad.bat:**

```
call notepad
```

**Links that I've looked at:**

- [General flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112081/set-an-external-exe-as-topmost)
- [SetWindowPos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle)
- [SetParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312535/can-you-launch-a-process-on-top-of-the-topmost-window-csharp-wpf)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you run notepad from a btach file and not run it directly? Your code will only make the CMD window (DOS prompt) topmost, not Notepad

Comment: Have you tried `System.Diagnostics.Process`? Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823518/calling-batch-file-from-c-sharp) question, might help!

Comment: @ThomasWeller -This is just a dummy program to check if it's possible. My real batch file contains numerous commands, most of them are background (such as installing drivers), but one needs a user interaction in order to continue. My question is if it's even possible

Comment: @devRicher - My process is `System.Diagnostic.Process`.. The example you gave is just another implementation of the same thing I did. BTW I've tried the result given there before, didn't work.

Comment: It should be possible. Just run Notepad on its own. If needed, first run the batch file as a process and then run notepad as another process.